# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<Map<String, String>>>'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an async function that gets some data from SQL server. The error points to the last line of this function. I am using an `await` when I call this function in another file. Why am I getting this error? I need to end up with a `List<Map<String, String>>` to use in another file. I already tried doing `res = json.decode(res) as List<Map<String, String>>;` but this didn't work.

```
Future<List<Map<String, String>>> getServerList() async {
  //...

  //res is a String here
  //example of data inside res variable: [{ServerName: Server1, ServerIP: IP1, DatabaseName: DB1, PortNum: 1433, Status: null}, {ServerName: Server2, ServerIP: IP2, DatabaseName: DB2, PortNum: 1433, Status: null}]
  var res = await SqlConn.readData("declare @Status nvarchar(4000) exec spHandheldServerList @Status output"); 

  //...     

  //Changes res from a String to a List<dynamic>
  res = json.decode(res);

  return res; //ERROR POINTS HERE
}
```

Comment: Please provide your example as a valid json - [{ServerName: Server1, ServerIP: IP1, DatabaseName: DB1, PortNum: 1433, Status: null}, {ServerName: Server2, ServerIP: IP2, DatabaseName: DB2, PortNum: 1433, Status: null}]

Comment: @sigmapie8 I wrote it like that because that's what the `SqlConn.readData` function outputs.

Comment: can you paste the result from `  res = json.decode(res);`

Answer (score 0):

When `json.decode` parses JSON, the runtime type of the returned value is going to be one of the following depending on the JSON string that was parsed:

- `null`
- `bool`
- `int`
- `double`
- `String`
- `List<dynamic>`
- `Map<String, dynamic>`

(In the last two cases, every item in the list or map will also be one of these types.)

In your case, it is `List<dynamic>`, which is not implicitly convertible to any other kind of list. You need to call either `cast` or `map` (or both) in order to explicitly convert the list to the type you need. And because you're dealing with `Map`s that's nested within a `List`, not only do you need to convert the outer `List`, you also need to convert the inner `Map`s.

```dart
final res = await SqlConn.readData(...);

final dynlist = json.decode(str) as List<dynamic>;

final listOfMaps = dynlist.map((ch) => (ch as Map<String, dynamic>).cast<String, String>());

return listOfMaps;
```

---

If the structure of the JSON is known beforehand, you want to be parsing any `Map` you have into a data class. This gives you type safety and reliability that are impossible to have from maps alone.

```dart
class ServerMetadata {
  final String serverName;
  final String serverIP;
  final String databaseName;
  final int portNum;
  final String? status;
  
  const ServerMetadata(this.serverName, this.serverIP, this.databaseName, this.portNum, this.status);
  
  factory ServerMetadata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ServerMetadata(
      map['ServerName'] as String,
      map['ServerIP'] as String,
      map['DatabaseName'] as String,
      map['PortNum'] as int,
      map['Status'] as String?,
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
final res = await SqlConn.readData(...);
final dynlist = json.decode(str) as List<dynamic>;
final servers = dynlist.map((map) => ServerMetadata.fromJson(map));
```

Comment: This returns an error when printing out `listOfMaps.toString()`: `Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast`

Comment: @TheMortiestMorty Then the JSON you are trying to serialize isn't actually a `List<Map<String, String>>`. You should check the value of the JSON string you are getting to see what types you are actually dealing with.

Comment: `await SqlConn.readData...` outputs a `String`, then `json.decode` turns it into a `List<dynamic>`.

Comment: There's an example of the data output by `await SqlConn.readData` at the bottom of the question. Maybe the outer brackets should be stripped first? Not sure what to do here...

Comment: @TheMortiestMorty Your problem is `PortNum: 1433`. That's going to be parsed as an `int`, not a `String`. If you absolutely have to have your maps as `Map<String,String>`, replace the `cast<String, String>()` with `map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value.toString()))`. However, you are also going to have a problem with `Status: null`, so I'd recommend leaving it as `Map<String, dynamic>` or, better yet, creating a data class to parse the map into rather than trying to coerce everything into strings.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the 'Future' from
`Future<List<Map<String, String>>> getServerList() async` to return the list you need of type `List<Map<String, String>>`.
Basically your variable stops being of type 'Future' when you resolve it with the await and convert it to json (which already returns the list of type `List<Map<String, String>>`)

Comment: `json.convert` returns `dynamic`, and if the root node of the JSON is an array, the runtime type of the object returned by `json.convert` will be `List<dynamic>`, which isn't implicitly convertible to `List<Map<String, String>>`. And if you take the `Future` part out of the return type of the function, it prevents the function from being able to be marked as `async`.